# Spring RabbitMQ breakpoint inside MessageListener onMessage method

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I have this code on consumer side of a Spring RabbitMQ based application -

```
public class MyReceiver implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {

    public MyReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("some_name")
    private SomeDependency dep;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
        try {
            String messageString = new String(message.getBody());
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(messageString)) {
                LOGGER.info("Received Message is:" + messageString);

                dep.someMethod();
                channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

When I put break at the first line inside try, control reaches the breakpoint and the goes on to execute the LOGGER.info() call after it but the further lines do not execute most of the time and control moves out somewhere else before it can get there. How do I ensure that entire code inside onMessage is executed?

Here is the console output -

INFO : mypackage.MyReceiver - Received Message is:{"some thing here"}
DEBUG: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Closing cached Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2)
ERROR: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
DEBUG: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-utTZhTES5HFCGizQGiFWqg=tx.mt.sessionstats.recvq}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
DEBUG: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer - Received shutdown signal for consumer tag=amq.ctag-utTZhTES5HFCGizQGiFWqg
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:554)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
DEBUG: org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@4ddced80 testClass = MyReceiverUnitTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null],

Answer (score 0):

Add logging of exception inside *catch* block (never catch exceptions without any useful action in catch block), and add logging in last line of *try* block.

**EDIT:**

I found this topic: http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/reply-code-406-reply-text-PRECONDITION-FAILED-unknown-delivery-tag-td21310.html

And I think that call to *channel.basicAck* may be redundant, try to remove it.

Comment: There was some code inside the catch block - removed it to anonymize the code. Anyway, no exception is being thrown.

Comment: Ok. Logging in end of try block is triggered?

Comment: LOGGER.info() call inside try also executes most of the time - I have added a console output to original post. Thanks

Comment: I added link which may be useful.